# Merge two STRING_SPLIT

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

Consider the problem below:
I have two strings for split:

```
STR1 = 'b;a;c;d;e'

STR2 = '3;1;4;2;5'
```

I want to split and merge these two strings based on their index, such that the result is:

```
b -> 3
a -> 1
c -> 4
d -> 2
e -> 5
```

I tried with `STRING_SPLIT`, but `order by` sorts them all.

```
SELECT A.VALUE, B.VALUE FROM (
    SELECT VALUE, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY VALUE) AS RW
    FROM STRING_SPLIT('b;a;c;d;e', ';')
) A
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT VALUE, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY VALUE) AS RW
    FROM STRING_SPLIT('3;1;4;2;5', ';')
) B
ON A.RW = B.RW
```

This produces the following result:

```
a   1
b   2
c   3
d   4
e   5
```

Comment: for reference to SQL 2016 `STRING_SPLIT`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql

Comment: you could use 2 queries with `row_number` and join them, don't have 2016 so can't test, although you maya need to order the results so that may not work

Comment: you physically want that arrow?

Comment: @Tanner - I tried with that row_number, but problem is that, order by needs to be used with row_number. That's why the items are being sorted.

Comment: It's easier for us to help if you provide your complete query with sample data rather than a remark about having tried something that didn't work.

Comment: @scsimon - No I do not want that arrow, they are just meta fore of column separator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps something like this?

```
declare @STR1 varchar(64) = 'b;a;c;d;e'

declare @STR2 varchar(64)  = '3;1;4;2;5'

;with cte as(
select
    value
    ,RN = row_number() over (order by (select null))
from
    STRING_SPLIT(@STR1,';')),

cte2 as(
select
    value
    ,RN = row_number() over (order by (select null))
from
    STRING_SPLIT(@STR2,';'))

select
    c.value + d.value
from
    cte c
    inner join 
    cte2 d on c.RN = d.RN
```

Comment: That worked absolutely fine. Thanks a lot.
I was trying `Order by null`.

Comment: Do we know if STRING_SPLIT will always return the results in the order of the values provided? If not this might work well until the string list is longer and then it may start flaking out.

Comment: I have searched extensively on this previously @SeanLange and couldn't find any hard tests on it. Like you, I'd think there would be a way for it to get out of order but there is nothing on this. However, i haven't seen a user-built split function that returns a table in an arbitrary order, so i wouldn't expect Microsoft to do this. I'd expect them to keep it explicit. The docs state the return of an example without explicitly talking about the order. *SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.', ' ')* states it would return (and give it in order)

Comment: I tend to agree. I know I have seen many people asking about the order and I have never seen any confirmation from MS that the order is guaranteed.

Comment: well, usually when MS didn't mention anything on it, it is not guaranteed right ? :)

Comment: @Squirrel fair argument, but their verbiage on the example of  *Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet* was explicit that the results would be (and then they list the split in order). If the results could have varied I would have thought otherwise. Granted, I use Jeff's splitter anyway.

Answer (score 2):

STRING_SPLIT does not return a row number. It would not work for your requirement.

Here i am using Jeff's DelimitedSplit8K
http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/

```
declare @STR1 varchar(20) = 'b;a;c;d;e'

declare @STR2 varchar(20) = '3;1;4;2;5'

select  s1.Item , s2.Item
from    DelimitedSplit8K (@STR1, ';') s1
    inner join DelimitedSplit8K (@STR2, ';') s2 on  s1.ItemNumber   = s2.ItemNumber
order by s1.ItemNumber
```

Answer (score 1):

I like the solution that you tried. It works if you `order by` a literal value instead of `VALUE`:

```
SELECT A.VALUE, B.VALUE FROM (
    SELECT VALUE, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS RW
    FROM STRING_SPLIT('b;a;c;d;e', ';')
) A
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT VALUE, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS RW
    FROM STRING_SPLIT('3;1;4;2;5', ';')
) B
ON A.RW = B.RW
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it without depending on `STRING_SPLIT()` function:

```
DECLARE @xml       AS XML, 
        @xml2      AS XML, 
        @str       AS VARCHAR(100), 
        @str2      AS VARCHAR(100), 
        @delimiter AS VARCHAR(10) 

SET @str='b;a;c;d;e' 
SET @str2 = '3;1;4;2;5' 
SET @delimiter =';' 
SET @xml = Cast(( '<X>' + Replace(@str, @delimiter, '</X><X>') 
                  + '</X>' ) AS XML) 
SET @xml2 = Cast(( '<X>' + Replace(@str2, @delimiter, '</X><X>') 
                   + '</X>' ) AS XML) 

SELECT a.value, 
       b.value 
FROM   (SELECT n.value('.', 'varchar(10)') AS value, 
               Row_number() 
                 OVER ( 
                   ORDER BY (SELECT 100))  AS SNO 
        FROM   @xml.nodes('X') AS T(n))a 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT n.value('.', 'varchar(10)') AS value, 
                          Row_number() 
                            OVER ( 
                              ORDER BY (SELECT 100))  AS SNO 
                   FROM   @xml2.nodes('X') AS T(n))b 
               ON a.sno = b.sno
```